# Javascript - Children are preventing the parent to be clicked

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I'm experiencing a weird situation. I want to make a whole Bootrstrap component clickable, and handle that click by Javascript. However, when I click on the element, JS is detecting that I have clicked on one of its children instead of on the parent.

HTML:

```
<div
    class="card"
    on-tap="showViewer"
    data-id$="[[article.id]]"
>
    <img
        class="card-img-top img-fluid vertical-image"
        src$="{{getArticleImage2(article)}}"
        onerror$="this.src={{defaultimage}}"
        alt="{{getArticleDescription(article)}}"
    />
    <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column justify-content-center py-2">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-start align-items-center mb-2">
            <img class="icon-sm mr-2 img-fluid" src={{getFavIcon(article)}}>
            <span class="medium-text">
                {{getSources(article)}}
            </span>
        </div>
        <p class="card-text primary-headline medium-text">
            {{article.schema:headline}}
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
showViewer: function(e, detail) {
    let id = e.target.dataset.id;
    console.log(e)
    let clicked;

    if (id == this.article1['id'])
        clicked = this.article1
    else if (id == this.article2['id'])
        clicked = this.article2
    else if (id == this.article3['id'])
        clicked = this.article3
    else{
        for(let article of this.articles){
            if(article['id'] == id){
                clicked = article;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('article-viewer').data = clicked;
    Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('article-viewer').display = true;
    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
}
```

If I click on the `card` image, my JS code detects that `e` is the `img` instead of the `<div class="card">` element. I want that, anywhere I click in the card component, the `e` refers to the parent card div instead of to the exact component which has been clicked inside the card.

Comment: you can use [Element.closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to look for the closest parent element.

Comment: You should be using strong equality `===` not loose equality `==` which will invite errors and misunderstanding.

Comment: For the answer to your problem, please see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation and here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: @theblackgigant I used your recommendation and got what I was expecting. If you post the answer I can select yours as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function testClick() {
alert("Well then, I fired.");
}

function stopProp() {
window.event.stopPropagation();
}
```

```css
div {

text-align: center;
background: red;
color: blue;
display: block;
padding: 2px;
}

span {
background: #FFF;
display: block;
margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="testClick();">
  <span>My parent has a click event.</span>
  <span onclick="stopProp();">My parent has a click event, but I do not propagate</span>
</div>
```

Set your click event to be on the parent. When you click on a child element, and there is a click event on the parent, the parent will fire. Given that you have not stopped propagation on the child.

Comment: Why would you create a function just to call a single other native function? Doesn't that seem redundant to you? Also, you should never use inline event attributes, you need to use addEventListener() or you will be limited to a single event and it will cause problems if later in another part of the code you create another onclick event for that element.

Comment: @StephenMIrving This is just an example. This is also easier to understand.

Comment: You are teaching and reinforcing bad practices. You give no indication that the way you are doing it is a way that should never actually be repeated. People come here to learn and you are leading them astray. It being "easier to understand" is irrelevant because someone who understands and repeats the wrong way to do it is worse off than a person who repeats but doesn't yet understand the right way to do it. Concepts are much easier to learn than bad habits are to unlearn. I do not understand the view of, "Lets just teach them the wrong way because it is easier and then teach them right later"

Comment: @StephenMIrving The question was answered in a way to be easily understood.

JS with JS, HTML with HTML and CSS with CSS.

Best practice is sometimes harder to understand and read. When you start coding, it's best to fully understand your language and read about best practices and improve your coding style to suit.

If the answer is not satisfactory, please answer in your own capacity.

Comment: @StephenMIrving Like I said, if the answer is not satisfactory, please post your own. I'm not going to go into a debate about this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204492/discussion-between-marius-and-stephen-m-irving).